# If you have servlets why do you need rest web service in java

Tags: java, rest, servlets

How is Rest WS different form regular Servlets , What additional features do REST provide

Comment: also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314658/difference-between-restful-webservice-and-httpservlet)

Comment: welcome to SO, avoid getting downvote on questions and ask only quality questions.

Answer (score 0):

Representational State Transfer (REST) is a software architecture style for building scalable web services.

A servlet is a small Java program that runs within a Web server. Servlets receive and respond to requests from Web clients, usually across HTTP, the HyperText Transfer Protocol.